# Wordpress URL rewrite not working

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, url-rewriting

I've added this to my functions.php page:

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
   add_rewrite_rule('^leaf/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?page_id=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

But when I go to http://example.com/leaf/1234, I get a funky 404 page. Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: You have problems in your regular expression. Try this (leaf)+?\/([0-9]+) . You can use an online regular expression tester like https://regex101.com/ to build your expression.

Comment: @DayronGallardo still directs me to a 404 page

Comment: Have you tried to flush and regenerate the rewrite rules database?